# Unable to pass the value between components using props in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-hooks, react-props

I am new to react. My ask is simple - I have 2 components - table and highcharts line chart. I want an option where user can click on the table cell and it will change/reload the data in line chart accordingly.

I tried using the props to pass the clicked value to the another component, but somehow its not working. I followed couple of articles but somehow nothing is working probably because i am new to this and not sure what exactly i need to look for (state/props/context/hooks).

Can someone please take a look and guide me where i am going wrong ?

Component 1:

```
export default function Table() {
    const [state, setstate] = useState({cont:""})

    const changeState = (x) => {
      setstate({cont:x});
      alert(x)  //  Alert is working fine
    };

  return (
      <><Table
        thead={['#', 'Company Name', 'Avg Count (in M)']} tbody={[{
        values: [1, 'ABC Inc', '2939,110']
      }, {
        active: true,
        values: [2, <div onClick={()=>{
          changeState('XYZ')
        }}>XYZ</div>, '1268,147']
      }]} /></>);

}
```

Component 2:

```
export default function Timeseries(props) {
  console.log(props.cont)   // Getting undefined here
  const lineChartOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Count '
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },
    xAxis: {
      categories: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec'
      ]
    },

    legend: {
      layout: 'horizontal',
      align: 'center',
      verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {}
    },
    tooltip: {
      split: true,
      valueSuffix: ' millions'
    },
    series: getdata()

  };


  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader> <span>{props.cont}</span></CardHeader>
      <CardBody>
        <div id='chart-container' className='w-100 h-100'>
          <SpectrumChart
            containerProps={{ style: { height: '100%', width: '100%' } }}
            // colorPalette="twelveColor"
            options={lineChartOptions}
          />
        </div>
      </CardBody>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Edit:

This is how i am rendering chart

```
import React from 'react';
import Timeseries from './Timeseries';

export default function Tab() {
  const { tab } = React.useContext(Context);
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Row h='70' pb='1'>
        <Col pl='1'><Timeseries /></Col>
      </Row>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: where is the part where you render the chart?

Comment: how are you passing props to Timeseries ? I can only see the Table component

Comment: @MorKadosh Added the details of component where i am using the Timeseries

Comment: @Ashish , you mean how i am importing it in Timeseries component ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be passing any props from parent component to children,

There are some rules and limitations when it comes to using Props in ReactJS,

- First thing to learn is Props can be passed only from the parent component to children, not the other way around.

And in your component 2, the reason you're getting undefined is that Props were never passed into component from the parent.

And also if I assume props were passed, in that case, you're calling it wrong.
Your initial state is an Object, so you'd have to call it like this

```
export default function Timeseries(props) {

  console.log(props.state.cont)   // If the state was passed from the parent, then this will log the state to console.


  const lineChartOptions = { 
     ...
```